# How to use PHP regex flags in Twig

Tags: php, regex, twig

I need to use regex flags in Twig regex_replace filter.

eg..

PHP regex: `~<div\ class="myclass">[\s\S]*?</div>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<a[^>]*>.*?</a>~gx`

Twig: `regex_replace('~<div\ class="myclass">[\s\S]*?</div>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<a[^>]*>.*?</a>~gx','');`

In this case, flags (`gx`) are not working. Need quick help on this.

Comment: You do not need `gx` in this case, remove them. `g` is just not used as `preg_replace` replaces all non-overlapping occurrences, and `x` is a VERBOSE flag that makes unescaped whitespace in your regex mean nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable PCRE in twig by using extensions

https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions

After that you will have access to `preg_replace()` in Twig

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter from Twig.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html